# activeadmin filter on dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have a table of `companies` and I'd like to have a dropdown form on the activeadmin dashboard header bar and so when a `company` is selected on it, I can pass it along to a page's `scope_to` method.

I've already found a way to pass the data to the `scope_to` method, but I don't know how to place the dropdown on the dashboard header; I've tried defining a form and then calling it with:

```
form do |f|
    render partial: 'form'
end
```

And then placing the form in `activeadmin/resource/_form.html.arb`, but that won't work. Same for all other approaches so far.

Update:

I've found a "way" to have the partial in the dashboard header; I can use:

```
proc{`render partial: 'admin/dashboard/set_current_company'}
```

on a menu's label and it works as intended...except I get two selects, only one of which works.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean passing to the page's scope filter, could you elaborate? Do you to have a dropdown and then when a company is select you take them to the companies admin page?

Comment: I want to have a dropdown consisting of multiple companies; when a company is selected, it should filter the content on the page based on that company.

I have a scope in the activeadmin model that calls a scope on the actual model, but I don't know how to pass this selected company to the scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed a partial containing a regular Rails form anywhere to maintain the session company_id.  The form can submit to a regular Rails controller or a [custom page](https://activeadmin.info/10-custom-pages.html) action.

Comment: I've edited the original post; the issue at hand is placing the form partial on the header menu.

Comment: Override ActiveAdmin::Views::Titlebar perhaps?